# Magento 2.4.4 READONLY You can't write against a read-only replica

Tags: reports, redis, magento2.4.4, docker

The website keeps going down throwing error.

> {"0":"READONLY You can't write against a read-only replica.","1":"#1
> Cm\RedisSession\Handler->read() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Redis.php:98]\n#2
> Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler\Redis->read() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler.php:212]\n#3
> Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler->callSafely() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler.php:125]\n#4
> Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler->read()\n#5 session_start()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:204]\n#6
> Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->start() called at
> [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Session/Interceptor.php:122]\n#7
> Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session\Interceptor->start() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:141]\n#8
> Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->__construct() called at
> [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth/Session.php:102]\n#9
> Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session->__construct() called at
> [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Session/Interceptor.php:14]\n#10
> Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session\Interceptor->__construct()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121]\n#11
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66]\n#12
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#13
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:170]\n#14
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:276]\n#15
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:239]\n#16
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34]\n#17
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]\n#18
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#19
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:170]\n#20
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:276]\n#21
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:239]\n#22
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34]\n#23
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]\n#24
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#25
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:206]\n#26
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->parseArray()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:182]\n#27
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:276]\n#28
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:239]\n#29
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34]\n#30
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]\n#31
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#32
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:109]\n#33
> Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->__construct() called at
> [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:14]\n#34
> Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->__construct()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121]\n#35
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66]\n#36
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#37
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:115]\n#38
> Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at
> [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]\n#39
> Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:264]\n#40

I have Redis installed[image] via Docker on Plesk Control Panel running on CentOS operating system. I restart Redis to get the website back online again, attached is the Redis Container configuration.

Also below is env configuration for Redi

```
    'cache' => [
        'frontend' => [
            'default' => [
                'backend' => 'Magento\\Framework\\Cache\\Backend\\Redis',
                'backend_options' => [
                    'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                    'database' => '0',
                    'port' => '6379'
                ]
            ],
            'page_cache' => [
                'backend' => 'Magento\\Framework\\Cache\\Backend\\Redis',
                'backend_options' => [
                    'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                    'port' => '6379',
                    'database' => '0',
                    'password' => '',
                    'compress_data' => '1',
                    'force_standalone' => '0',
                    'connect_retries' => '10',
                    'read_timeout' => '30',
                    'automatic_cleaning_factor' => '0',
                    'compress_tags' => '1',
                    'compress_threshold' => '20480',
                    'compression_lib' => 'gzip'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'allow_parallel_generation' => false,
        'graphql' => [
            'id_salt' => 'xxxxxxxxx'
        ]
    ],
   'session' => [
        'save' => 'redis',
        'redis' => [
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => '6379',
            'password' => '',
            'timeout' => '15',
            'persistent_identifier' => '',
            'database' => '2',
            'compression_threshold' => '2048',
            'compression_library' => 'gzip',
            'log_level' => '1',
            'max_concurrency' => '15',
            'break_after_frontend' => '5',
            'break_after_adminhtml' => '30',
            'first_lifetime' => '600',
            'bot_first_lifetime' => '60',
            'bot_lifetime' => '7200',
            'disable_locking' => '1',
            'min_lifetime' => '60',
            'max_lifetime' => '2592000'
        ]
    ],
    'cache_types' => [
        'config' => 1,
        'layout' => 1,
        'block_html' => 1,
        'collections' => 1,
        'reflection' => 1,
        'db_ddl' => 1,
        'eav' => 1,
        'customer_notification' => 1,
        'config_integration' => 1,
        'config_integration_api' => 1,
        'full_page' => 1,
        'translate' => 1,
        'config_webservice' => 1,
        'compiled_config' => 1,
        'vertex' => 1
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't face this issue yet, but I found some responses to this issue on other sites, they said "Re-installing redis-server seems to have helped".

There is a related issue for Magento 1 on github, you can take a look: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis/issues/155

Btw, the page caching database number should be set to `1` instead of `0` because the default caching was used `0`.

> Important: If you use Redis for more than one type of caching, the
> database numbers must be different. It is recommended that you assign
> the default caching database number to 0, the page caching database
> number to 1, and the session storage database number to 2.

Reference: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cache/redis/redis-pg-cache.html